# AutomatedWorkflowActionException: Incorrect type defined for automated workflow in Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on WorkFlow in Hybris. I created workflow Template with respective workflow actions and decisions. If I am using adminCockpit and performing actions. Then my workFlow is working fine.

but I am want to perform corresponding actions through HMC now. Suppose Action1 is assigned to user A. Now User A will login through HMC and check his inbox. He can also accept or decline workflow action from there.

When I am performing workflow actions through HMC, then I am getting this error :

```
de.hybris.platform.workflow.jalo.AutomatedWorkflowActionException: Incorrect type defined for automated workflow. containerCreationJob should implement de.hybris.platform.workflow.jalo.AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob[HY--1]
```

Code :

```
import de.hybris.platform.workflow.jobs.AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob;
public class AbstractOrderCreationJob implements AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob
{
        // some code
}
```

Can anybody dig into this error. please help me to solve this prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. Actually Whenever you are performing actions through admincockpit, it will look `de.hybris.platform.workflow.jobs.AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob` interface with respective `perform(final WorkflowActionModel action)` action.

If you will try to perform the same task through HMC, it will look deprecated `de.hybris.platform.workflow.jalo.AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob` interface. So In case of HMC you have to implement deprecated AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob. And deprecated interface is asking `WorkflowAction` class to override perform method. So the Idea is to convert this obeject class to model using `modelService`.

What You have to do is that ..

1. Implemented deprecated `AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob` in your Automated Job Class.

   ```
   import de.hybris.platform.workflow.jalo.AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob;
   import de.hybris.platform.workflow.jalo.WorkflowAction;
   import de.hybris.platform.workflow.jalo.WorkflowDecision;

   public class xyzJob implements AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob 
   {
       @Override
       public WorkflowDecision perform(final WorkflowAction action)
       {
           //suppose you want to get Order
           final WorkflowActionModel workflowActionModel = modelService.get(action);
           final OrderModel order = getAttachedOrder(workflowActionModel);
           ........ more code ..........
       }

   }
   ```
2. Like that You can work on depreciated `AutomatedWorkflowTemplateJob`. This won't give you `Incorrect type defined for automated workflow` error. And you can perform the same actions through HMC also.

Hope this will help you. Good Luck!